# What is the best way to add unallocated space located before to Ubuntu 12.04 partition with GParted live?

Tags: gparted

I have my 1TB disk partitioned in three main parts:

- /dev/sda1 NTFS SYSTEM 100 Mb
- /dev/sda2 NTFS Win7 469.12 Gb (too
  large!!)
- /dev/sda3 extended 373.36 Gb

  - /dev/sda5/ ext4 358.21 Gb
  - /dev/sda6 swap 15.15 Gb

I want to resize my /dev/sda5 adding the unallocated space...but it is located left to sda5/. How can I organize it? I am working with GParted, but when I use Resize/Move option on sda5/ the unallocated space don’t appear on left.  Thanks for getting back to me.

[image: Image from GParted]

[image: Details about sda5/]